# The state does not change in react

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

Hi everyone I just learned react and have the following problem: When I change hideFormAdd in App.js, the statusForm in FormAdd.js only gets the first unmodified default value.

```
//file App.js
<TaskForm open={this.state.hideFormAdd}></TaskForm>
```

```
//file FormAdd.js
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        statusForm: this.props.open
      }
    }
```

Comment: How are you changing the hideFormAdd in App.js?

Answer (score 5):

That is because the constructor is not called on subsequent renders, it is only called once to initialise the component. To update your state when the properties change, you must implement [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.open !== prevProps.open) {
    this.setState({statusForm: this.props.open});
  }
}
```

Note that in this example, you may not need to use the `state` at all, you could perhaps just refer to `this.props.open` in your component, thus eliminating the complexity of managing prop updates.

Answer (score 1):

As FMCorz Said you can do that inside componentDidUpdate().  and also you can do within render() as well

```
    render() {
        var statusForm= this.props.open;

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your app component, you must do a function to change the state.

```js
state = {
  hideFormAdd: true,
}
handleHideForm(){
  this.setState({hideFormAdd: !this.state.HideFormAdd})
}
```

in your render function:

```js
<button onClick={()=> this.handleHideForm()}> hide/show </button>
<TaskForm open={this.state.hideFormAdd}></TaskForm>
```

now in your **TaskForm** component you don't need to use the state , you can use **this.props.open** without to make her value in state